# Woocommerce Add To Cart for variable product in Idstore Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce, woothemes

I have been having a problem of add-to-cart not appearing for the variable products. I have set the price for every variation.

While getting into the details, I found out that **`wcaddtocartvariation_params`** variable was **undefined** in the file add-to-cart-variations.min.js.

This is the case in IDSTORE theme. But, when I use the Twenty Fourteen theme instead, it is working fine.

Getting into more details, I suspect the source of problem is somewhere here:

```
#idstore/code/functions.php
if(classexists('WooCommerce')) {
    $scriptdepends = array('wc-add-to-cart-variation');
}
```

This is line no. 68 in the file. When I comment this line, it starts working for the IDSTORE theme also.

Can somebody please explain to me why this happens, and how to resolve it? Any help is appreciated.

Just for better understanding, this is the link to the website I am working [here.](http://boonstan.webfactional.com/product/krav-maga-global-p1-practitioner-1-dvd-2/)